# How to put an image and a text in a ListView in Android

Tags: android, xml, image, listview

I'm kind a new here so, I have a problem.. I have this menu a Listview specifically and I want to put an image before the text.. this is my menu2.java..

```
public class menu2 extends Activity {

private ListView listApps;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu2);

listApps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

String str[] = new String[] {"Messaging", "Phone Dialer", "Simple Math", "Splash", "Exit","Quit Application"};
//final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.activity_list_item,android.R.id.text1, str);

listApps.setAdapter(adapter);

listApps.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View aview, int position,
            long id){
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Intent i1 = new Intent(menu2.this,Messaging.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(menu2.this,PhoneDialer.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;                  
        case 2:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(menu2.this,SimpleMath.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;                  
        case 3:
            Intent i4 = new Intent(menu2.this,Splash.class);
            startActivity(i4);
            break;                  
        case 4: 
            Intent i5 = new Intent(menu2.this,Exit.class);
            startActivity(i5);
            break;                                      
        case 5:

            AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(menu2.this);
            alt_bld.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit application?");
            alt_bld.setCancelable(false);
            alt_bld.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish(); 
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //  Action for 'NO' Button
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
            alert.setTitle("Confirmation");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            alert.show();                   

        }
    }
});
}
```

then i have my menu2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

i have a problem putting an image view on the left and a textview on the right.

Comment: Just put both of them in the LinearLayout...

Comment: so I will create another linear layout?.. so it will be 
    <LinearLayout>
        <imageview></imageview>
        <textview></textview>
    </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see how you've set up your layout with your ListView element? You'll have to also create a separate layout for each row in your list, something like listview_row.xml or whatever you choose to name it. In addition to that, you'll have to create a custom Adapter that will bind your textView and ImageView to each ListView row. This gives you so much more control over your list rows. I've written a blog post about this very topic. Have a look and let me know if you need any more help. Good luck!

http://jadebyfield.blogspot.com/2012/10/custom-listview-with-textviews-and.html